# Luabind inheritance: self not defined

Tags: inheritance, lua, luabind

I just got myself into weird problem with Luabind. I want to inherit C++ classes from Lua, but the way described in Luabind documentation just doesn't work.

```
function MyGame.__init()
    Game.__init(self)
end
```

This piece of code just crashes the application, because `self` seems undefined (returns `nil` if printed out).

I'm using wrapper struct as described in documentation.

```cpp
struct GameWrapper: Game, luabind::wrap_base{
GameWrapper()
    : Game()
        {}

virtual int Loop(void){
     call<int>("Loop");
}

static int default_Loop(Game* ptr){
    return ptr->Game::Loop();
}


static void Lua(lua_State *lua){
    luabind::module(lua)
    [
    luabind::class_<Game, GameWrapper>("Game")
        .def(luabind::constructor<>())
        .def("Loop", &Game::Loop, &GameWrapper::default_Loop)
    ];
}
};
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but way described in Luabind doc just doesn't work.

Yes it does. You just didn't do it right. Specifically, you didn't notice the use of the `:` instead of the `.`. Which has [a well-defined meaning in Lua when declaring a function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9):

```
function MyGame:__init()
    Game.__init(self)
end
```